# CouchDB free also for businesses?

Tags: couchdb

Often you can use open source projects for free as long as you don't earn money yourself. In that moment you often need to purchase another license in exchange for cash, naming [mySQL](https://shop.oracle.com/pls/ostore/f?p=dstore:2:4559354748404836%3a%3aNO%3aRP,2%3aPROD_HIER_ID:58095029061520477171389&tz=2:00) as an example. But I can't find any information like that about couchDB. So I wonder if it is totally for free, even if you build a business onto it. Can you confirm that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about softwar licensing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [Licenses](http://www.apache.org/licenses/) link on the [Apache Couch DB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) site, which links to the main Apache license site.

In general, the Apache licenses are pretty open and allow you to do just about whatever you want with them, provided that you attribute the original work you use to Apache, distribute the license when you distribute any Apache projects, and note any modifications you made.

To determine what the License means for your *specific* use, please contact a friendly lawyer to advise you on legal issues.

Comment: Is there any point about paying something? I don't see anything, if I search through that file for "cost", "pay" and terms like that (which I did before sending my question here, of course)

Comment: @erikb - Added my interpretation of their license.

Comment: Okay. So it not unlikely that I don't have to pay anything for using CouchDB.

Comment: @erikb - Yes, you likely don't have to pay anything.

Answer (score 6):

CouchDB, like all Apache projects, is licensed under The Apache License which permits all uses, including commercial ones. You most certainly do *not* have to pay anything to use CouchDB.

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Answer (score 2):

Your example about MySQL is incorrect. You are free to use the open-source version of MySQL even in a commercial environment. It is true that there is a paid for version if you want extra features or support but like CouchDB there is no restriction on using MySQL in a commercial environment.

Comment: MySQL is only free until it is used in a commercial deliverable (http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/index.html). So if you sell a product that includes MySQL, then you are obligated to pay license fees to Oracle. If all you do is host a website, then you are okay. CouchDB is exempt from this since it uses the Apache license.